# Minimal hosting control panel or API?

Tags: linux, control-panel

I have many VPS managed via Proxmox. Each VPS is a dedicated server for 1 single domain.

I am looking for a solution to manage email accounts, FTP, databases remotely, possibly through an API for that domain.

I've been looking at ISPConfig, or Webmin -- which look like the most promising, but kind of overkill for what I have to do.

Is there a barebone software that will automatically configure PHP 5.3, MySQL, IMAP email, and let me manage accounts via an API or via shell?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try http://gnupanel.org/
there are many others of course http://wiki.debian.org/HostingControlPanels

if you are thinking of cloud and easy roll out of common web based apps I think http://www.jumpbox.com can worth the money